# Inserting one to many relationship

Tags: laravel

I've got three tables: blogs, posts, blog_post. Here is my code.

```
$post = new Post(); 
$post->title    = HTML::entities(Input::get('title'));
$post->content  = Input::get('content');
$post->status   = isset($_POST['save']) ? 2 : 1;
$post->save();

$blog = Blog::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();

$post = $blog->posts()->insert($post);
```

And I get:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '47' for key 'PRIMARY'

I have one to many relation ships. A post can belong to many blogs.

Comment: Sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Well, one post belongs to many blogs and a blog can have many posts.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of a many-to-many relationship, which is different from a one-to-many relationship as you stated.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. So any ideas how on saving a post I can add a record pointing for `post_id` & `blog_id` in `blog_post`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Laravel so I won't give an "Answer" but it looks like you've set up a one-to-many relationship, and you're trying to create the post twice - once in the save() line and once in the insert() line.  I assume the framework has a way to set up many to many relationships and to "add" a blog to a post or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at13 answer is correct. You are saving the post and then trying to insert it again through blog relationship.

According to your comments you should have:

```php
$post->has_many_and_belongs_to('blog');
$blog->has_many_and_belongs_to('post');
```

With that in mind, to create many to many relationships, you should use `attach()`.
For instance:

```php
$post = new Post;
$post->title = "Foo Bar";
// ...
$post->save();

$user = Auth::user();
$blog = $user->blogs()->first();
$blog->posts()->attach($post);
```

**Obs:** I don't quite understand the concept of a post belonging to more than one blog.

Comment: Because a user can have more than one blog and they can add a post for many blogs they've created. = )